# C# Square root expression just won't work

Tags: c#

I've got a very simple little program to solve quadratic equations, in the main it works but for some reason it won't calculate square roots. I just get an error saying `NaN` but I can't see how it's not a number?

```
int a = Convert.ToInt16(txta.Text);
int b = Convert.ToInt16(txtb.Text);
int c = Convert.ToInt16(txtc.Text);          

listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(Math.Sqrt(((b * b) - (4 * a * c)))));
```

Comment: For what input is throws this error? Tell us numbers.

Comment: what line is causing the problems?

Comment: As a guess: one of the textboxes contains something which is not convertible to an integer, the integer is inizalized as 0 and this causes the problem, because the sqrt of 0 is NAN.
The solution: sanitze your inout with Integer.Tryparse

Comment: Are you sure `b*b -4*a*c` is not negative?

Answer (score 3):

The conversions aren't the cause because if they didn't convert properly or if there was an overflow you'd get a `FormatException` or `OverflowException` respectively.  None the less, since you're doing math you might want to convert to double types.

```
double a = Convert.ToDouble(txta.Text);
double b = Convert.ToDouble(txtb.Text);
double c = Convert.ToDouble(txtc.Text);
```

I believe your expression: `(b * b) - (4 * a * c)` is the problem.  If it evaluates to a negative number, that will result in a `NaN` result.

See [Math.Sqrt Method on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sqrt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Another reason to use double: it is possible that one of the integer multiplications silently overflows.

Comment: Oh, thanks, hadn't thought that the test data I was putting in was giving me a negative, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It's likely getting a negative number. It might help to convert it to a double instead of an Int16, because Int16 will round every time.

Comment: No; `Convert.ToInt16()` will throw an exception.

Comment: Yes, but the problem has nothing to do with `Int16`.

Comment: It does though http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d0bahsf(v=vs.110).aspx look at remarks

Comment: That's a different function.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/basyfs27